# pros of using webservice libraries(RESTKIT/ASIHTTP Request) over NSURLconnection for ios webservices

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, restkit

I would like to understand advantages of using RESTKIT/ASIHTTPREquest libraries over the traditional NSURLconnection for calling RESTFUL/SOAP webservices. I had used both type of webservices(RESTKIT/SOAP) in my project with nsurlconnection and I am successful... 
Hence anyone pls help me to understand the benifits of going to RESKIT/ASIhttprequest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit has good integration with CoreData. ASIHTTP uses blocks which can be nice for firing one off requests. The more I use different network libraries, the more I think there is no one-solution to this problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with ASIHTTPRequest. Yeah, it is great and all but it was last updated May 2011 and the author has stopped development on it. See http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;